# How do I handle encoding in a Firefox (Jetpack) Addon's response.text?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have code like this:

```
Request: require('request').Request
_makeCall:function(callback){
Request({
        url: 'URL-TO-API',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1",
        content: {
          op: 'OPERATION-TO-CALL,
          password: 'super-sec,
      user: 'me@gmail.com'
        },
        onComplete: function (response) {
            if(response.status == 200){
                callback(response.text);
            }
            else{
                callback('');
            }
    }
});
req.post();
}
```

The API will return a XML struct encoded in ISO-8859-1. The returned data, in response.text, will contain Swedish characters like ö, ä and ö. Unfortunately characters like this will be displayed as �.
The html page I use in the Panel, where the text is displayed, look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

….

I'm really stuck here, anyone have any idea on handling this encoding issue?

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` (which `Request` is most likely based on) defaults to UTF-8 encoding. For a different encoding the response of your server needs to specify the charset in the `Content-Type` header, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

This will make sure the response is converted to Unicode correctly. `<meta>` tags won't help.